# Syntax highlighting for Cake build scripts (tag cakebuild)

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

Syntax highlighting for Cake build scripts isn't available for questions tagged with just [cakebuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cakebuild) today.

The [cakebuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cakebuild) should default to `lang-cs` just as [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23), as it's 9 times of 10 C# build scripts that the code samples in answers and questions contains.

Example of tag used on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cakebuild)

Comment: If it's C#, it should just be tagged with [[tag:c#]], and that will take care of the syntax highlighting problem.

Comment: Of course it will, it'll also clutter C# tag which has led to moderators denying edits which add that tag just for syntax highlighting.  Also many people just add the cakebuild tag which leads less readable questions.  If you see another task runner like Gulp they've added lang-js to that. https://stackoverflow.com/tags/gulp/info

Comment: @CodyGray I don't think there is any harm in adding the language hint as there is none at the moment and for you it is a 10 second task. Typing this comment was more effort.

Comment: Sure, it's not a matter of difficulty, @rene, it's a matter of risking breakage when we start adding syntax highlighting hints to tags. I guess I can try it...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Done. The [cakebuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cakebuild) tag now has `lang-cs` set as its default syntax highlighting.

Let me know if that introduces any undesirable breakage.

Comment: Thank you very much for doing this, mich appreciated!